# Image colorization ConvNet accurancy and loss still improving, but output having more artefacts

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have following CNN:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32)      320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 256)       1179904   
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 32, 32, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 128)       295040    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 32)      18464     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 256, 256, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 16)      4624      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 2)       290       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,707,794
Trainable params: 4,707,794
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And i training it with this params:

- Dataset size: 150 000
- Optimizer: Adam
- Batch size: 128
- Loss function: MSE

And i have these graphs:

[image]
[image]

We can see, accurancy and loss improving whole time. But the problem is with output. When i evaluate each epoch model with my test dataset, best epoch is 15.

Here we can see comparation between epoch 15 and 60.

[image]

Is this overfitting and how to prevent it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct - this is an example of overfitting. You can see this starting to occur around epoch 10, where the accuracy of the training set starts to rise higher than that of the validation set.

This is caused by the model beginning to memorise the training set patterns too much, and so it can't generalise well on unseen data (your validation set).

You don't appear to have any regularisation layers in your model, so I'd definitely recommend adding some dropout layers. Dropout works by randomly 'turning-off' nodes, so the model is forced to learn other routes through the network and so helps prevent overfitting. This [blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/) does a good job of explaining.

Start with a dropout of 0.1 and see if the point at which the training accuracy and validation accuracy start to differ begins at a later epoch than epoch 10. So if for example training acc > validation acc now starts at epoch 20, then you know dropout is having a positive effect, and you can decide what to do from there.

As always, make changes in small steps so you can see what's happening.

Comment: I tried add some dropout layers, but without improve. So i think, this will be the maximum.